# What is the space requirement of many trees?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I was asked the space requirements of my project and I wasn't sure about the answer, so I am asking here. Here is what I do:

1. I am building a number of perfect binary trees (let's say `m`).
2. Every leaf indexes one point (i.e. that we keep the data stored and
   every tree indexes the points that are stored there).

My thought is that the space requirement is: `O(n*d + m)`, where `n` is the number of points, `d` is the dimension of a point and `m` is the number of the trees, but I am telling this by experience, not sure if I fully understand it!

Can anyone help?

---

To be honest, every leaf contains a number of points, `p`, but I think that I will be able to work out the result, if I will get an answer to my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect binary tree with n leaves, the total number of nodes is 2n - 1, which is O(n). More generally, if you have a collection of perfect binary trees with n total leaves, the total number of nodes will be 2n - 1. Therefore, if each of the n leaf nodes stores a d-dimensional point, the total space usage is O(nd).

The number of trees m here actually doesn't need to show up in the big-O space analysis. Think of it this way: if you have m trees, assuming each is nonempty, then you have to have at least n leaf nodes (at least one per tree), so we know that m = O(n). Therefore, even if you do account for the space overhead per tree as O(m), the total space usage of O(nd + m) is equivalent to O(nd).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, that helps a lot, but I still have a question. You say: "Therefore, if each of the n leaf nodes stores a d-dimensional point, the total space usage is O(nd)". That's not the case. Maybe, I wasn't clear, sorry. Imagine we have 5 trees. Instead of having every tree storing the actual points inside it, we maintain a vector (visible to every tree) that stores the actual points. Then, every leaf of every tree stores the index of the point that would be stored there. Hope now it's more clear. Would this change the resultant O(nd)? Oh and yes, you're answer is already helpful.

Comment: @gsamaras Asymptotically, that doesn't change anything. Let's suppose each leaf just stores the index. If there are n entries in that vector, there are O(n) tree nodes and O(nd) space used storing those points, so the total space usage would be O(n + nd) = O(nd).